# Разветвление сценариев в SELENIUM IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Всем привет. Начал изучать силениум, и возник вопрос. У меня есть 2 состояние моего сайта:

1. Я залогинен в системе.
2. Я не залогинен в системе.

В рамках одного теста нужно как то указать разные ветки выполнения тестовых сценариев исходя из того, залогинен ли пользователь в системе или нет. Подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: хм. написать кодом? как еще?

Comment: Ну ясно что не на камне вытесать )) А какими методами это реализовать?

Comment: if ? Ну то есть это же элементарно, IF залогинен: {сценарий 1} ELSE не залогинен: {сценарий 2}

Comment: Я тоже про IF думал но не очень понимаю как тут он работаете.
Т.е. я записываю какие то действия. Ставлю if а дальше? В target и value что писать?